# HTML link changes browser bar but not actual page

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, href, supersized

We use this code to change the page:

`<a href="http://mydomain.com/#/people/page/" target="_self">Page</a>`

...which changes the URL in the browser bar but not the actual page. If you hit enter at the end of the URL in the browser bar it redirects to the correct page.

Why is the link not actioning a page change? This is being used with the http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ full screen background changer with titles. The links are being used in the title field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the # pound sign. Your browser thinks that a URL with a pound sign is the same page so it doesn't redirect or refresh. When you press enter you are refreshing the page.

Try making the URL http://mydomain.com/people/page/ instead

Comment: Sometimes it takes another pair of eyes to spot it :)